# Get queries executed on BigQuery by user

Tags: google-bigquery

There is some way to get all queries executed on Google BigQuery by user, with information like time spent, bytes processed and so on?

These informations are listed on Query History, for example, but can I get it from an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... can I get it from an API?

Yes. You can use [`Jobs: list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) to gather job information that is available for a six month period after job creation.

You can also consider using [`CLI`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool)

```
bq ls -j -a
```

Finally, you can consider using [`Audit Logs`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs)